# select items that have multiple matches in a normalized table

Tags: php, mysql, search, normalization

I have a table that stores a bunch of objects.  Each object can have many colors which are stored in a normalized table connected by the object_id.

If I go

```
SELECT `object_name` FROM `objects`
  LEFT JOIN `object_color` USING `object_id`
    WHERE `object_color` IN ('red', 'blue');
```

Then I get objects that are 'red' **OR** 'blue'.  I need to get all objects that are 'red' **AND** 'blue'.  If I go:

```
SELECT `object_name` FROM `objects`
  LEFT JOIN `object_color` USING `object_id`
    WHERE `object_color` = 'red' AND `object_color` = 'blue';
```

Then I get nothing as there's only one object_color in each line and it can't be both. Also, in actuality, the colors are id's with names in another table.  I simplified everything here for the sake of the question.

I need to be able to search for an unlimited number of colors.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

object_color is only in the object_color table.

And any object will have any single color once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select object_name
From objects
Where object_color In('red','blue')
Group By object_name
Having Count(Distinct object_color) = 2
```

Btw, you never mention from which table the `object_color` column derives. If it is from the `object_color` table:

```
Select O.object_name
From objects As O
    Join object_color As C
        On C.object_id = O.object_id
Where C.object_color In('red','blue')
Group By O.object_name
Having Count(Distinct C.object_color) = 2
```

---

<strike>The above query assumes that a given `object` row could have not have multiple `object_color` rows of the same color. However, as Joel C noted, if it were possible for an `object` to have multiple `object_color` rows of red or blue, then that requires a different query. :</strike>

```
Select ...
From objects As O
Where O.object_id In    (
                        Select C1.object_id
                        From object_color As C1
                        Where C1.object_color = 'red'
                        )
    And O.object_id In  (
                        Select C1.object_id
                        From object_color As C1
                        Where C1.object_color = 'blue'
                        )
```

Yet another solution:

```
Select O.object_name
From objects As O
    Join    (
            Select C1.object_id, C1.object_color
            From object_color As C1
            Where C1.color In('red','blue')
            Group By C1.object_id, C1.object_color
            ) As Z
        On Z.object_id = O.object_id
Group By O.object_name
Having Count(*) = 2
```

Comment: What if there are multiple 'red' and/or 'blue' entries for an object? This would give you results where 'red' appears twice and never blue, but exclude results where both 'red' and 'blue' appear multiple times.

Comment: @Joel C - That is an important piece of schema information that isn't stated in the OP. If that were possible, then I'd probably handle that through multiple In clauses.

Comment: @Thonas: and @Joel: Doesn't your `Distinct C.object_color` already take care of that issue?

Comment: @ypercube - Not enough coffee today. You are correct. I already handled it through distinct.

Comment: Each object will can have unlimited distinct colors.  No color will be on an object twice.

I had been thinking about the multiple 'IN' statements for each color but seemed like it could add up to a lot of sub-queries if there were a lot of colors.  Hadn't considered 'having count' which seems pretty slick.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `ON` rather than `USING`:

```
SELECT o.object_name
FROM objects o
  JOIN object_color oc
    ON o.object_id = oc.object_id
WHERE oc.object_color IN ( 'red', 'blue' )
GROUP BY o.object_id
HAVING COUNT(o.object_id) = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                              FROM ( 'red', 'blue' )
                            )
```

Assuming that it is not possible for an object to have many rows with same colour.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a multi join

```
SELECT `object_name` FROM `objects`
  LEFT JOIN `object_color` USING `object_id`
    WHERE `object_color` = 'red'
  LEFT JOIN `object_color` USING `object_id`
    WHERE `object_color` = 'blue' ;
```

Comment: Since it's a left join, you'll only want to include the records where both the results from 'red' and the results from 'blue' are not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use INTERSECT if it is supported in the SQL you're using.

```
SELECT object_name
FROM objects o, objects_color oc
WHERE object_color = 'red'
and o.object_id = oc.object_id

INTERSECT

SELECT object_name
FROM objects o, objects_color oc
WHERE object_color = 'blue'
and o.object_id = oc.object_id
```

This will intersect the two tables and only show rows that have both red and blue color matched with the same object name.